# Create Own Column Property in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i want to create my one own property for every column.

ex. every column has description property but i require one more property for me.

i want required for auto code generate from that property.

what is best way for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Object Explorer, right click the column in question and click properties.

This should open the Column Properties Window.

Select [Extended Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx), and here you can add your data.

Answer (score 2):

[Using Extended Properties on Database Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx)

To add a new extended property to the `SafetyStockLevel` of the `dbo.Product` table use the following command:

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
  @name = N'MS_DescriptionExample', 
  @value = N'Minimum inventory quantity.', 
  @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = dbo, 
  @level1type = N'TABLE',  @level1name = Product,
  @level2type = N'COLUMN', @level2name = SafetyStockLevel;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Extended properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx) are exactly what you're looking for. They can be specified for any database object (including columns) and retrieved using system functions/procedures.